# Lightning message channel

Tags: lightning-web-components

The documentation says that we can leverage Lightning Message Channel (Beta) to communicate between 2 lightning web components on different pages. However, while researching I came across a post that says it cannot be used with Sandbox and Production. Is it correct that it cannot be used with Sandboxes?

Answer (score 0):

**Winter 20:**

I think you are talking about this [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/10/lightning-message-service-developer-preview.html).

The LMS was in Developer preview which means it is only available Developer orgs and scratch orgs for now and not in production and sandboxes.

**Spring 20:**

In Spring 20 the feature was moved to beta and was made available.

This feature is available in Lightning Experience. To create a Lightning message channel, use Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.